# Response is not getting for adgroup_name and match_type for bing keywordlevel in Google Analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I am confused in Google Analytics i.e.,Response is not getting for adgroup_name and match_type for bing keywordlevel data in Google Analytics & for google it is getting.

I am using google analytics version 3.

Why not in bing keywordlevel data?

**Bing:**

dimensions  = "ga:campaign,ga:adGroup,ga:keyword,ga:adMatchType";

source/medium = bing/cpc

**Google**

dimensions  = "ga:campaign,ga:adGroup,ga:keyword,ga:adMatchType";

source/medium = google/cpc

Comment: I am not completely sure I understand your question.  Google does not have a lot of data for Keyword.   https://analytics.googleblog.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure-accessing.html

Comment: But for google campaign_name ,adgroup_name,Keyword_name,match_type is getting.But for the bing only campaign_name and keyword_name is getting.What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Your question is unclear maybe you should add some data to show what the problem is.  Bing is not Google and neither are Google Analytics the data will not be the same.